# Converting Azure Powershell commands to Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a Powershell script using Azure Powershell to update an Virtual Machine Scale Set (under Azure Service Fabric) to add/remove the certificates that are used by the associated service fabric virtual machines. This script works as intended and I have the following commands (I've removed some of the other logic to focus on the issue):

```ps
# This gets the Virtual Machine Scale Set object
$virtualMachineScaleSet = Get-Azvmss -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $myVMScaleSetName

# Example of removing items from certificate items from the VMSS object.
$virtualMachineScaleSet.VirtualMachineProfile.osProfile.Secrets[$mySecretIndex].VaultCertificates.RemoveAt($myCertificateIndexThatIWantToRemove)

# Example of creating new certificate config
$newCertificateUrl = (Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $myKeyvaultName -Name $myCertificateName).SecretId
$newCertificateConfig = New-AzvmssVaultCertificateConfig -CertificateUrl $newCertificateUrl -CertificateStore "My"

# Example of adding new certificate to the VMSS object
$virtualMachineScaleSet.VirtualMachineProfile.OsProfile.Secrets[$mySecretIndex].VaultCertificates.Add($newCertificateConfig)

# Committing the update to VMSS
Update-Azvmss -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroupName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $virtualMachineScaleSet -VMScaleSetName $myVMScaleSetName
```

The above script works fine. However, I'm now trying to convert each of the above commands to Azure CLI. The way the script will invoke means that I cannot mix and match Azure Powershell and Azure CLI commands in the same script. The commands I have so far are causing problems:

```ps
# This gets me the Virtual Machine Scale Set object
$virtualMachineScaleSet = az vmss show --name $myVMScaleSetName --resource-group $myResourceGroupName | ConvertFrom-Json

# Trying to RemoveAt gives the error: MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
$virtualMachineScaleSet.VirtualMachineProfile.osProfile.Secrets[$mySecretIndex].VaultCertificates.RemoveAt($myCertificateIndexThatIWantToRemove)

# Not sure the CLI equivalent commands of this
$newCertificateUrl = (Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $myKeyvaultName -Name $myCertificateName).SecretId
$newCertificateConfig = New-AzvmssVaultCertificateConfig -CertificateUrl $newCertificateUrl -CertificateStore "My"

# Trying to Add gives the error: MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
$virtualMachineScaleSet.VirtualMachineProfile.OsProfile.Secrets[$mySecretIndex].VaultCertificates.Add($newCertificateConfig)
```

So my questions are.

1. What are the CLI equivalent commands for the Azure Powershell script?
2. Why doesn't the VMSS object in the Azure CLI script seem to be the same? (At least in that I cannot change the VaultCertificates array)

Thank you in advance

Comment: When I run `$virtualMachineScaleSet.VirtualMachineProfile.osProfile.Secrets[0].VaultCertificates.RemoveAt(0)` with Az Powershell, it shows the same error `Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."` Can you reconfirm this cmd works fine with Az Powershell?

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue? If yes, can you post an answer?

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: What is the reason you do not give any response?! If works then accept it, if not, give the issue, it's a simple response.

Answer (score 0):

All the PowerShell you used can change into two equivalent CLI commands.

One for remove:

```
az vmss update --resource-group $myResourceGroupName --name $myVMScaleSetName --remove virtualMachineProfile.osProfile.secrets index
```

One for add:

```
az vmss update --resource-group $myResourceGroupName --name $myVMScaleSetName --add virtualMachineProfile.osProfile.secrets '{"sourceVault": {"id": "resourceId"},"vaultCertificates": [{"certificateStore": null,"certificateUrl": "certificateUrl"}]}'
```